# Can someone explain me the following code?? especially how ((pid=fork())==0) really works

Tags: unix, fork, parent-child, child-process, pid

Can someone please explain me the following code.

```c
int main(int argc,char** argv) {
int status;
int pid;
// Create a process (fork)
if ((pid=fork())==0) {
// Child process
printf("[%s] Child process (PID=%d)\n",timestamp(),getpid());
exit(0); // Terminate OK
} else {
// Father process
printf("[%s] Father process (PID=%d)\n",timestamp(),getpid());
wait(&status); // Wait for child to finish
}
return
```

What does the `((pid=fork())==0)` really mean?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you know about [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)? What do you know about what it can [return](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html#RETURN_VALUE)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude
I know that fork creates a new process and the new process becomes the child. and it can either return a positive value, a negative one, or a zero.
i don't know how to gets created or where exactly in the code. 
and i know that the PID is the process ID, that's all

Comment: You will understand `if ((pid=fork())==0)` (or `pid=fork()l if (pid==0)`) when you `printf("fork returned %d\n", pid);`